# Getting the actual nth-of type position of last-of-type

Tags: css, selenium, highcharts

So here is my problem. I want to loop through every point of a line chart in HighCharts using Selenium. I figured a way to start from path:nth-of-type(1) to path:last-of-type. However, it goes from right to left and I would love to have it going from left to right (I'm peaky I know).
Thus, if I could find a way to start from last-of-type to nth-of-type(1), I would be very pleased. However, I don't know how to get the equivalent nth-of-type(position) of last-of-type in order to decrease it by 1 every time I loop through it.

Here is the code I have so far (the right to left one):

```
public static boolean isLastPoint(int series,WebDriver driver){
        if(series > 1){
            WebElement last = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("g.highcharts-series-group > g:nth-of-type(2) > path:last-of-type"));
            WebElement current = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("g.highcharts-series-group > g:nth-of-type(2) > path:nth-of-type(" + (series) + ")"));
            return last.equals(current);
        }
        else return false;
    }

public static void overview(WebDriver driver, boolean active) {
        if(active){
            wait(driver,By.id("highcharts-0"));
            WebElement chart0 = driver.findElement(By.id("highcharts-0"));
            LineChart lc0 = new LineChart(driver,chart0);
            int series = 1;
            while(!isLastPoint(series-1,driver)){
                lc0.hoverOverLineChart1(series, "");
                series++;
            }
        }else return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findElements` for this:

```
int count = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("g.highcharts-series-group > g:nth-of-type(2) > path:last-of-type")).size();
```

Then use the `count` to iterate backwards.